# Dynamically bind buttons to a list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a mvvm application and a form which show buttons. Each button on the xaml form need to be binded to a corresponding list item. E.g. in the list we can have: Items(Item(1, Mercedes), Item(3, BMW), etc). I need to show just those buttons which exists in a list when form open. The list is dynamically populated on form start. Here is the example of a button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ChooseCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static local:Car.Merecdes}" >
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="165" Height="125">
            <Image x:Name="PathIcon1" Width="50" Height="35" Source="/Resources/Images/Mercedes.png" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="Mercedes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,20,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
     </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `ItemsControl` (such as a `ListBox`) to display the items and a `DataTemplate` to define what each item should look like. Perhaps something like this:

In Resources:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=ChooseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Param}">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="165" Height="125">
                <Image x:Name="PathIcon1" Width="50" Height="35" 
                    Source="{Binding ButtonImageSource}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="5,20,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

In XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemCollection}" .../>
```

Note that for this to work, you'd need to add a `ButtonText` property and a `string ButtonImageSource` property to your item class. Please see the [*Data Templating Overview*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information about data binding.

Comment: Bizarrely, the [`ButtonBase.CommandParameter` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN is not working at the moment, but I have a feeling that it is not a `DependencyProperty`, so you can't data bind to it... I *could* be wrong about that though.

Comment: O.K. Then, what to do about CommandParameter? One more thing, I need to write those buttons in a grid (form-wide), is ListBox good candidate for this ?

Comment: You can also use an `ItemsControl` instead of a `ListBox` if you don't need to know which item is selected. See MSDN for the differences.

Comment: Microsoft have fixed their broken link and it turns out that `CommandParameter` is also data bindable as it *is* a `DependencyProperty`. Therefore, just add another property to your item class and bind that too.